# Error with google api service account

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, access-token, google-domain-api

I am trying access google api for my domain by using service account. This is my tutorial https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The first: I access "console.developers.google.com" and create new project. I added calendar API to my project. After that I create credential OAuth "service account". I use this key and create and access_token with role "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar". I got access_token successful.

The second, I access "admin.google.com" and go to manage API client access. I added my client ID with role "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"

But when I use this access to access GET request
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CalendarID]?access_token=???

I always get message

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Seem maybe my access_token can't access to my domain. This is my source code to create access_token.

```
$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://key.pem', 'notasecret');

$header = array("alg" => "RS256", "typ" => "JWT");
$header = base64_encode(utf8_encode(json_encode($header)));
$exp = time() + (60 * 60); 


$jwt_cs = array(
   "iss" => "ClientEmail@MyApp",
   "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
   "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token",
   "exp" => $exp,
   "iat" => time(),
   "access_type" => "offline"
);
$jwt_cs = base64_encode(utf8_encode(json_encode($jwt_cs)));

openssl_sign($header.'.'.$jwt_cs, $sign, $private_key, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption');

$sign = base64_encode($sign);

$jwt = $header.'.'.$jwt_cs.'.'.$sign;
$login_data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    'assertion' => $jwt
);
$url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($login_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Can you show me my wrong?

Comment: you need to give the service account access to the domain.  I don't have access to a domain account so I cant help you test this.  But you "should" be able to take the service accounts email address and add it like you would any other user. This "should" give it access.

Comment: also try https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?key={AccessToken}  instead if your calendar id is wrong that could cause the error as well.   (yes I said Key not Access_token don't ask.)

Comment: I think I did it in https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients. I added my client ID to "Authorized API clients" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar " to One or More API Scopes

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client   <--- Client library :)

Comment: My calendar id is not wrong. I tested it in this page https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: I am using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71771/discussion-between-hoangvu68-and-daimto).